# Sense behind the empty subscript?

Tags: swift

Why does this even compile? What is the need for an empty subscript which obviously behaves like a function without parameters?

```
extension Array {
    subscript() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}

let array = [1,3,2]
print(array[]) // "0"
```

Note that it can also be used for an assignment, so it behaves like a computed property named `[]`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense but it doesn't make it invalid Swift code. No compiler/language can stop you from doing all the non-sense thing

Comment: why should it *not* work? Regarding the *need* - you defined it, think up a need.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this even compile

It compiles because you defined an empty-subscript extension to Array:

```
extension Array {
    subscript() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Array already has a subscript defined, whereby you supply an index number and get back the element at that index. This extension adds *another* subscript, whereby you supply nothing and get back the number zero.

Without that extension, this would *not* compile:

```
let array = [1,3,2]
print(array[])
```

> What is the need for an empty subscript which obviously behaves like a function without parameters

There's no "need"; it's a convenience. You could, after all, make exactly the same "objection" to subscripts in general! They do nothing that you cannot accomplish by methods. In fact, such methods exist; the subscript notation is merely a pleasant piece of syntactic sugar.